# Vue.js How to watcher before mounted() , can't get data from watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mount, watch

In the `async mounted()` part, it can't retrieve data from `this.point0` because it mounted before watch right? How can I fix this.

My goal is to update the p1 and p0 in mounted() whenever the new API is sent in watch

Can check out my code here https://jsfiddle.net/1eahf26q/

```
  data() {
    return {
      point0: [],
      point1: [],
    };
  },

  watch: {
   async breedKey (newVal, oldVal)  {
       try {
      this.promise = axios.get(new_url);
      const res = await this.promise;

      this.point0 = res.data.data[0].Freq;
      this.point1 = res.data.data[1].Freq;
   }
  },    

  async mounted() {
    await this.promise;

    let p0 = this.point0;
    let p1 = this.point1;
    const datapresent = [p0, p1, this.point1,];
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you code, it seems like a computed would do the job. Try moving your logic from `mounted()` to computed as

```
computed: {
    dataPreset() {
        return [this.p1, this.p2];
    }
 }
```

This would automatically return an updated `dataPreset` whenever `p1` or `p2` change.

**EDIT:**

As far as I have understood, you can definitely initialize your graph once you have the API data inside your watcher. You watcher could be like

```
watch: {
    selectedTrend: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(to) {
        this.trend = to.Trends;
        this.GetAPIData(to.Trends, to.DT);  //A method to get the sample API DATA
        this.InitializeGraph(); //A method which initializes your graph
      }
    }
  },
```

A sample sandbox created at: https://codesandbox.io/s/twitter-trends-fp0wn

Comment: Im rendering the line chart under mounted, so it might only receive dataset create within mount Im not sure, try compute already, notworking.

Comment: Why do you want to initialize the line chart in `mounted()`. It can be done whenever you are ready with the data @Charlie. I feel you are over-complicating a very simple requirement

Comment: @Charlie there are a lot of suggested improvements which you can find in the sandbox link. Answer updated.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/twitter-trends-kzxjp?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Could you please try to check out the sandbox, I really can't find an example that renders vue js chart without using mounted